# Cálculo con matrices

Tags: c

Tengo una matriz de enteros. Necesito crear una segunda matriz que sea el valor de la matriz -1. Ejemplo: si la primera fila es 3,6,1, en la matriz 2 debe ser 2,5,0.
Hice el código pero me devuelve cualquier resultado en la segunda matriz.

```
 int m1[3][3]= { {3,6,1},
                 {5,4,2},
                 {1,3,8}
               };


int m2[3][3];
int i, j;


for (i=0; i<3; i++){
  for (int j=0; j<3;j++)
      m2[i][j]= m1[i-1][j-1];
}
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
  for (j=0;j<3;j++)
      printf (" Matriz 1 %d \n", m1[i][j]);
}
printf ("\n\n");
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
  for (j=0;j<3;j++)
      printf ("Matriz 2 %d \n", m2[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: Estás poniendo `m1[i-1][j-1]` donde debería ser `m1[i][j]-1`. El 1 lo estás restando en los índices, con lo que estás accediendo a lo que había en la fila/columna anterior a la fila/columna `i`/`j`. De hecho, cuando `i` o `j` son cero, estarías accediendo a la fila/columna `-1`, lo que es un error que podría haber causado la terminación del programa.

Comment: Perfecto! Ahora funciona correctamente! Lo puedes poner como respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás poniendo `m1[i-1][j-1]` donde debería ser `m1[i][j]-1`.

Lo que quieres es acceder al elemento que está en la fila `i`, columna `j` y restarle 1. En cambio lo que estás haciendo es acceder al elemento que está en la fila `i-1`, columna `j-1`.

De hecho, cuando `i` (o `j`) son cero, estarías accediendo a la fila (o columna) `-1`, que no existe. Estarías accediendo fuera de los límites del array, lo cual es un error de programación que puede causar la interrupción de la ejecución de tu programa (por acceso a direcciones de memoria protegidas), o bien resultados impredecibles (por acceso a direcciones de memoria que, aunque no están protegidas, pertenecen a otras variables y no sabes a priori qué contienen).

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas cambiando de posicion la matriz m1 en vez de restarle uno al valor. Debe quedar asi

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++){

  for (int j=0; j<3;j++){

      m2[i][j]= m1[i][j]-1;

  }

}
```